# How can I render and position a scene inside a div element?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to position a 3D scene exactly within a div. The reason for this is that I can then easily place the 3D scene on several pages of the site just by adding a div.

I would like to be able to:

1. Specify the relative or absolute position of the div and the renderer to render to that position accordingly.
2. Change the size of the div, and the 3D scene to scale appropriately. (With cropping of the scene on one axis if the aspect ratio is not identical to the renderer).

I cannot get a simple situation to work. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? (See below for my attempt).

[image: Misaligned 3D image]

HTML:

```
<div class="three_d_renderer"
     style="width: 800px; height: 500px;
            border: 1px solid #aaa;"></div>
```

JS Code:

```
var ThreeD = {
    init: function(element){
        var camera, scene, renderer;

        var width = element.offsetWidth;
        var height = element.offsetHeight;

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
            75,
            width/height,
            1, 10000
        );
        camera.position.z = 1000;

        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        var mesh = ThreeD.make_cube(20,20,100);
        mesh.position.x = 0;
        mesh.position.y = 0;
        mesh.position.z = 100;

        scene.add(ThreeD.make_floor());
        scene.add(mesh);

        renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(width, height);

        $(element).append(renderer.domElement);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    },
    make_material: function(){
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: 0xff0000,
            wireframe: true
        });
        return material;
    },
    make_cube: function(x,y,z){
        var geometry, mesh;

        geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(x,y,z);

        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
            geometry,
            ThreeD.make_material()
        );
        return mesh;
    },
    make_floor: function(){
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
            new THREE.CubeGeometry(1500,1000,10),
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                color: 0xc0c0c0
            })
        );
        return mesh;
    },
};
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('div.three_d_renderer').each(function(){
            ThreeD.init(this);
        });
});
```

Comment: everything looks fine at jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/MMJvz/). Maybe you are missing some css or js here?

Comment: Styles. Indeed I had a conflicting style statement. Thanks for the pointer.